# Is javac failing on optimize my code?

Tags: java, javac, jit, cpu-cache

I have been testing cpu cache optimization and one simple test I did was summing a 2048x2048 matrix of integers inside nested loops, firstly i tried with sequential index(always jumping to the next memory integer) and then with a long width memory access(jumping to the 2048th next integer), I ran these pieces of code 1000 times each one and then I got the average execution time of each one, the test was executed on an Intel Core 2 Duo E4600 2.4 GHz with no other process that could harm the execution time on background and the results were:

> Sequential index: average: 8ms.
>
> Long width memory access: average: 43.

Here is the source code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] matrix = new int[2048][2048];
        
        long tInitial = 0;
        long tFinal = 0;
        
        long [] avgExecTime = new long[1000];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < avgExecTime.length; i++) {
            fillWithRandomNumbers(matrix);
            
            tInitial = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            sumSequentially(matrix);
            
            tFinal = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            avgExecTime[i] = tFinal - tInitial;
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(avgExecTime).sum() / avgExecTime.length);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < avgExecTime.length; i++) {
            fillWithRandomNumbers(matrix);
            
            tInitial = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            sumRandomly(matrix);
            
            tFinal = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            avgExecTime[i] = tFinal - tInitial;
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(avgExecTime).sum() / avgExecTime.length);
    }
    
    public static void fillWithRandomNumbers(int [][] matrix) {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = r.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static long sumSequentially(int [][] matrix) {
        long total = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                total += matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
        
        return total;
    }
    
    public static long sumRandomly(int [][] matrix) {
        long total = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                total += matrix[j][i];
            }
        }
        
        return total;
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why didn't java compiler optimized the method sumRandomly considering that sumRandomly and sumSequentially have the same final result?
2. Would java compiler be considering that could exist a thread changing my matrix parameter values while the sum is happening and that could change the results?

I have already tried without using methods and doing everything on the main method and the result is almost the same.

Comment: Those two methods aren't equivalent if the arrays are jagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in hexafraction's answer,the type of optimizations you are requiring are not viable. Anyway, there is a tiny optimization possible that i believe java compiler is taking, and that is because the times are different.

I am posting this answer just to make these terms become more visible, because i think they are important.

### The array access function

In Java language, all the called non-primitive variables are references, it means that the data is not directly accessible, and probably not sequentially stored.

Your data type is long, that is primitive, but you are storing them into an array, that is not primitive. When you try to access the values of your array like `matrix[i][j]` the JVM will have to perform at least three operations. Find the reference for the `matrix` object, find the reference to the `[i]` item and then finally find the reference to your value `[j]`.

As i said, the values will probably not be sequentially stored, so in most cases, the caches will not help too much. Looking to your code we can see two different forms of access to the object, `matrix[i][j]` and `matrix[j][i]` always `i` with the outer loop index and `j` the index of the inside loop. In this scenario we can make a simple optimization on the first case, because the value of the first array access will return the same on all the `j` loops, so the compiler can see this and say, "Wait there! I don't need to find the same result every loop. I will cache this!", so your code will evaluate to something like:

```
public static long sumSequentially(int [][] matrix) {
    long total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        long[matrix[i].length] matrixi = matrix[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixi.length; j++) {
            total += matrixi[j];
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

On the second method, this is not real. The `j` index changes every internal loop, changing with him the first and second array access result in all loops.

### The cpu cache

I've made this example in C, because C is a valid scenario for the CPU caching, that i believe is your main doubt.

The results were:

> Sequential sum average: 2ms.
>
> Random sum average: 39ms.

So, we have almost the same scenario. C stores data in arrays sequentially,  in multiple dimensions matrices we have (considering `char[2][2]` as the type):

```
+--------------+------------+
| Ram address  | Item index | 
+--------------+------------+
| 00000120000  | [0][0]     | 
+--------------+------------+
| 00000120001  | [0][1]     | 
+--------------+------------+
| 00000120002  | [1][0]     | 
+--------------+------------+
| 00000120003  | [1][1]     | 
+--------------+------------+
```

The CPU caches data and instructions to don't need go back to the RAM to have them. When we are accessing data sequentially, the CPU fills the cache with the data next to the one we are getting, then he will have the next N values cached when we access one, the problem is when we have to access the N + 1 value, so the cache needs to get validate and there will come a batch of data moved from RAM.

When accessing data in the second way, you will jump various RAM address and then back. Almost every jump you make you will invalidate the cache, and the cache will be filled again, so you need more operations and the process goes slower. If you want to know more, i saw a [Gallery of Processor cache effects](http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/) some time ago.

The both languages have a similar behavior, but for different reasons i guess that is because you got confused.

Answer (score 2):

`javac` does not optimize anywhere close to this degree, while the JIT may. This gives the JVM an advantage in certain regards since the optimization may be tailored to the specific behavior observed at runtime, as well as the specific capabilities and quirks of the processor upon which the JVM is running.

You are also making an assumption about the Java Virtual Machine and its handling of arrays, particularly nested arrays. While languages such as C and/or Fortran handle multidimensional arrays with a rectangular data structure, Java does not (and as such allows "ragged arrays", that is for an int[][], `arr[0].length` need not equal `arr[1].length`.

This is implemented using an array of *object references*, where each object reference points to an `int[]` in your case. Obviously, Java does bounds checking, which is seemingly easier to detect and optimize if a *single* array is accessed in a tight loop, as opposed to the same index over multiple arrays.

Comment: I understand that javac doesn't make optimizations leaving this to the jit, but the strangest thing is that even when I do everything in the main method and run the code several times inside a loop to make JVM realize that there is no difference in the final result the optimization doesn't appear to happen, anyway thank you.

Comment: @BrunoSimasHadlich Normally one would not iterate an array in this manner, and this optimization is likely one that requires a fair amount of specific code to detect, which does not provide a tangible benefit given the cost to write and maintain it within the JIT itself.

Comment: @hexafraction if you are right, don't should be the `matrix[i][j]` equals to `matrix[j][i]` since you are making `i++` and `j++` and in both cases you will get two array references? The fact is, the outside variable only changes when the inside loop ends, the compiler can save the first reference in the first case. On the second case, for every inner loop, the access variable changes and you cannot store the reference for the first array, that is because the sequential access is faster, you don't have to call the first array access function in every loop, i guess.

Comment: @JeanJung Yes, your statement about the sequential access is consistent with both my answer and expectation. The reason for the difference between matrix[i][j] and matrix[j][i] is just the iteration order.